# Symfony4 request data empty with ajax call

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm new with Symfony4 so maybe this is a noob question. But can't figure
it out.

I'm trying to register a user with an ajax call:

```
this.form.post('/register').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then in symfony my controller method looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="register", methods={"POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $user = new User();
    // encode the plain password
    $user->setPassword(
        $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
            $user,
            $request->request->get('password')
        )
    );

    $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
    $user->setName($request->request->get('name'));

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->json(['success' => 'User created']);
}
```

The problem is that the data is always empty. The data is send correctly. When I dd the response in my controller I see this:

[image]

My headers etc. look like this:

[image]

Request payload looks like this:

[image]
When I try it with postman I get the same result. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form type on the back-end side to validate your new registrated user, check this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html). Don't forget to update your controller also.

Answer (score -1):

In your twig, you must define

`<script>
  let registerPath = "{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ path('register') }}";
</script>`

And in your js you can use your ajax post like that :

`this.form.post(registerPath).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});`

Hope that can help :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. The path is correct.